# Applying Excel VBA code in a module to all worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, module

I've been struggling with this for a few days.
I have the below code which copies and pastes value when a certain If condition is met (the workbook has live data feeding into multiple sheets every second).
The code is currently located in a module, as the IF condition can apply to all sheets in the workbook.

The problem I have is the code only runs on the activesheet.  I need it to run on all worksheets in the workbook.  I've tried multiple loops with no success.  Ideally I need the code to run across all sheets in the background (i.e. without activating them).  Any help will be appreciated.

```
Dim TimeToRun

Sub auto_open()
    Call SchedulePrices
End Sub

Sub SchedulePrices()
    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CopyPrice"
End Sub

Sub CopyPrice()
    Calculate

If Range("AM7") = "1" Then

    Range("AM10:AM69").Value = Range("K9:K68").Value
    Range("AL10:AL69").Value = Range("B9:AM68").Value
    Range("AM8:AM9").Value = Range("C2:C3").Value

End If

'run the timer sub
    Call SchedulePrices

End Sub

Sub auto_close()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CopyPrice", , False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopyPrice()
    Dim sht as Worksheet



    For Each sht in Worksheets
        If sht.Range("AM7") = "1" Then
            sht.Calculate

            sht.Range("AM10:AM69").Value = sht.Range("K9:K68").Value
            sht.Range("AL10:AL69").Value = sht.Range("B9:AM68").Value
            sht.Range("AM8:AM9").Value = sht.Range("C2:C3").Value

        End If
    Next

'run the timer sub
    Call SchedulePrices

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe want to bring `Calculate` into the loop and run `sht.Calculate` as well.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you @Bond

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Seems to work perfectly.  Wish I asked the question a few days ago!

Comment: FYI - leaving Calculate outside of the loop works fine. It calls Application.Calculate instead of Worksheet.Calculate. It works fine either way, but it would have been better to be explicit before.

Comment: Yep, of course. It just makes more sense to calculate and process each sheet as a unit. Or if one of the later sheets relied on earlier sheets values, it would make sense to calculate after the others have been updated. In this case, however, probably doesn't make much difference.